# Using Yield to make a function wait until something is true Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield

I'm trying to use Yield so my functions wait to spawn more enemies in scene if the max amount has been reached. But now the functions skips all this while cycle in its entirety.
I have never use yield so maybe I'm understanding wrong what it does while reading the documentation.
Also maybe there is a better way to do it.

```
while ( i < clonesASpawnear.Length)
    {          

        if (j <= endList)
        {      
                if (clonesASpawnear[i] == null)
                {

                    if (sPCurrent == sPMax)
                    {
                        sPCurrent = 0;
                    }                   

                yield return new WaitUntil(() => aliveEnemies < maxAmmoutOfEnemiesOnStage);

                clonesASpawnear[i] = Instantiate(enemyTypeList[j], spawnPoints[sPCurrent].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
                    clonesASpawnear[i].SetActive(true);
                    clonesASpawnear[i].GetComponent<EnemyMovement_DCH>().player = Target;
                    aliveEnemies += 1;

                    clonesASpawnear[i].GetComponent<EnemyDamageHandler_DCH>().SpawnerEnemies = this;
                    j++;
                    i++;
                    sPCurrent++;


                }
            }               

        else
        {
            j = startList;
        }            



    }
}
```

**Edited as requested: here is the update where the function is called**

```
 void Update()
{
    if (pdh.playerIsDead == false && roundOver==false)
    {

        playerAliveTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }



    if (waveNumer <= 3 )
    {



        timeForNextSpawn -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeForNextSpawn <= 0 && aliveEnemies == 0)
        {


            nextWaveTextUI.text = nextWaveText;

            int waitT = (int)waitTimeForNewWave;
            StartCoroutine(delayXSeconds(waitT));


            timeForNextSpawn = waitTimeForNewWave;
            auxWaveThisRound--;

            waveNumer++;

            spawnEnemies();

        }
    }
    else
    {

        if(aliveEnemies == 0 && auxWaveThisRound <= 0)
        {
            clearedRoundTextUI.text = clearedRoundText;
            roundOver = true;



            StartCoroutine(waiterReset());


        }


    }

    accuracy = successfulProjectiles / projectileFired;


}
```

And the complete function where the above code is

```
IEnumerator spawnEnemies()
{

    int percentForWave=0;
    int percentForType=0;

    int TotalEnemies = (int)enemySpawnsThisRound;
    if (waveNumer == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entro al wave 1");
        percentForWave = 20;
        percentForType = 20;
        startList = 0;

    }
    if (waveNumer == 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entro al wave 2");
        percentForWave = 70;
        percentForType = 70;
        startList = endList;

    }
    if (waveNumer == 3)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entro al wave 3");
        percentForWave = 10;
        percentForType = 10;
        startList = endList;
    }


    int enemiesThisWave = Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Round(TotalEnemies * ((decimal)percentForWave / 100), 1));
    int enemiesForType = Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Round(lenghtList * ((decimal)percentForType / 100), 1));

    endList = enemiesForType + startList;

    clonesASpawnear = new GameObject[enemiesThisWave];
    int i = 0;
    int j = startList;



    while ( i < clonesASpawnear.Length)
    {



        if (j <= endList)
        {
                if (clonesASpawnear[i] == null)
                {

                    if (sPCurrent == sPMax)
                    {
                        sPCurrent = 0;
                    }
                yield return new WaitUntil(() => aliveEnemies < maxAmmoutOfEnemiesOnStage);

                clonesASpawnear[i] = Instantiate(enemyTypeList[j], spawnPoints[sPCurrent].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
                    clonesASpawnear[i].SetActive(true);//lo activo
                    clonesASpawnear[i].GetComponent<EnemyMovement_DCH>().player = Target;
                    aliveEnemies += 1;

                    clonesASpawnear[i].GetComponent<EnemyDamageHandler_DCH>().SpawnerEnemies = this;
                    j++;
                    i++;
                    sPCurrent++;


                }
            }

        else
        {
            j = startList;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not what `yield` is supposed to be used for. I suggest you go and read the C# docs on that, also I'm assuming there's a more appropriate way to spawn things in Unity?

Comment: seems like that is what they are using it for , thats why I got confused https://answers.unity.com/questions/304394/have-a-function-to-wait-until-true.html

Comment: Can you show use the complete code? Is this running in a Coroutine? How and where is it called/started from?

Comment: @DavidG .. well depending on the usecase (Unity Coroutines) this might be exactly what `yield` is used for .. until now you can't judge that since we don't see the full code of how this loop is used yet.

Comment: Add some debug messages to see whats doing what

Comment: acording to the debug is not even entering the while now, really weird, if I remove the yield it works just fine and enters .

Comment: Have you heard of `WaitUntil`? In your `IEnumerator`, you can use `yield return new WaitUntil(()=>condition);` to make your coroutine wait until `condition` is satisfied.

Comment: @Daniel Im using WaitUntil() , "yield return new WaitUntil(() => aliveEnemies < maxAmmoutOfEnemiesOnStage);" but is not working, it just skips the entire function.

Comment: are you making sure these values of the condition are right? are you dealing with the `aliveEnemies` correctly when a enemy dies? Try to debug these values always you say it "skips", probably these values are being updated wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a while loop. Instead, use "Update()".

```
void Update() {

    if (aliveEnemies < maxAmmoutOfEnemiesOnStage && j <= endList)
    {      
            if (clonesASpawnear[i] == null)
            {

                if (sPCurrent == sPMax)
                {
                    sPCurrent = 0;
                }                   

            clonesASpawnear[i] = Instantiate(enemyTypeList[j], spawnPoints[sPCurrent].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
                clonesASpawnear[i].SetActive(true);
                clonesASpawnear[i].GetComponent<EnemyMovement_DCH>().player = Target;
                aliveEnemies += 1;

                clonesASpawnear[i].GetComponent<EnemyDamageHandler_DCH>().SpawnerEnemies = this;
                j++;
                i++;
                sPCurrent++;


            }
        }               

    else
    {
        j = startList;
    }   

}
```

This is the idea of the Update frame. Logic in here is hit every frame. It will only continue if the number of enemies is below the max. This method MUST go into a class that extends MonoBehaviour, or else it will not be invoked. Given the intended logic, it makes sense that this would be attached to some master "game monitoring" GameObject that is managing the meta of the game along with win states etc.

**EDIT** (After more content):
Heres one problem "spawnEnemies();". That is an IEnumerator, but you don't use "StartCoroutine(spawnEnemies())". So the method will literally not execute. There will be no errors, but nothing in the method will occur.

Comment: Im already using the Update to control if the time is right to call the function that spawn the enemies (Im making a wave based shooter), I would preffer an alternative in wich I would not have to change that. But I will look into it.

Comment: So if you want an alternative, you will have to provide us the entire file of code, as what is provided above is insufficient to give you alternative suggestions. I can only assume things like, "Is this in an IEnumerable method or a void?" etc.

Comment: @ Asyranok  I just edited and added the rest of the pertinent code.

Comment: Heres one problem "spawnEnemies();". That is an IEnumerable, but you don't use "StartCoroutine(spawnEnemies())". So the method will literally not execute. There will be no errors, but nothing in the method will occur.

Comment: After rereading your post, I think that is the root of the issues you are seeing. Fix that and everything should work. Keep an eye out for all places that you invoke an IEnumerator method, as this is an easy mistake to make - one I've made plenty of times.

Comment: @ Asyranok Im using   StartCoroutine(spawnEnemies()) on the Start(). but maybe the order is wrong, I will check if is that.

Comment: That was the problem, I was doing the StartCoroutine(spawnEnemies()) on the wrong order, tks a lot!!

Comment: waveNumer++;

            spawnEnemies(); Look directly under the code "waveNumber++". You are not using StartCoroutine there, so it will not run the code. Your spawning will only work on start up. Not as enemies are destroyed and more need to be spawned.